# Deserializing a data member that could be int or string c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, system.text.json

I've created an API endpoint that is receiving a List of objects. The 'AttributeValue' of the objects could be either a string or an int. Here is a generic version of my code:

```
public class b
{
  public List<a> myList {get; set;} = new List<a>();
}

public class a
{
   public object AttributeValue {get; set;}
}
```

The problem is, I need to know the original data type. When I check the type it tells me "System.Text.Json.JsonElement". I also tried something like the following:

```
if(b.myList[0].AttributeValue is int) { do something.. }
else if(b.myList[0].AttributeValue is string) {do something...}
else {throw error}
```

I always throw an error so I assume I am losing my original data type when I am deserializing. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 2):

try to cast to JsonElement

```
var json="{\"myList\":[{\"AttributeValue\":1},{\"AttributeValue\":\"2\"},{\"AttributeValue\":3},{\"AttributeValue\":\"4\"}]}";

var b =System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<b>(json);

if (((JsonElement) b.myList[0].AttributeValue).ValueKind.ToString()=="Number") ...
else
 if (((JsonElement) b.myList[1].AttributeValue).ValueKind.ToString()=="String")...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Oneof<>](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OneOf) nuget.

```cs
 OneOf<string, int> result = funcHere(b.myList);
            return result.Match<xxx>(
                stringValue =>
                {
                  // do some string procedure
                },
                intValue =>
                {
                  // do some int procedure
                };
```

Answer (score -1):

You can apply a custom [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1) similar to the one shown in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#deserialize-inferred-types-to-object-properties) to `AttributeValue` to deserialize to an `Int32` or a `string` depending on the incoming JSON value:

```cs
public class a
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectPrimitiveConverter))]
    public object AttributeValue {get; set;}
}

public class ObjectPrimitiveConverter : JsonConverter<object>
{
    public override object Read(ref System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        reader.TokenType switch
        {
            JsonTokenType.String => reader.GetString(),
            JsonTokenType.Number when reader.TryGetInt32(out var i) => i,
            //Add other cases as needed:
            //JsonTokenType.Number when reader.TryGetInt64(out var l) => l,
            //JsonTokenType.Number when reader.TryGetDouble(out var d) => d,
            //JsonTokenType.True => true,
            //JsonTokenType.False => false,
            _ => throw new JsonException(), // StartObject, StartArray, Null    
        };
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, value.GetType() /*, options */); // Passing options when ObjectPrimitiveConverter has been added to options.Converters will cause a stack overflow
}
```

Notes:

- While the [JSON standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-6) does distinguish between strings and numbers, it does not distinguish between integers and decimals that happen to have integer values.  Thus if your `AttributeValue` might contain an integer of value `1` or a double of value `1D`, System.Text.Json will serialize both as `1` and, when read back in, you will not be able to distinguish the type.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c0ug8Q).